# Events of AutoCompleteBox in WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I'm using the AutoCompleteBox of the silverlight toolkit in my WP7 application.
When the box has focus, the SIP (soft input panel) popus up. Good.

Now, I would like to be able to detect :

1. when the user selects a value in the
   AutoCompleteBox DropDown
2. when the user clicks on "enter" in
   the SIP, that means he validates his
       inputs

This should be 2 differents events as I have 2 differents things to do in both cases.

There's the SelectionChanged event, But I'm unable to make the difference...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .Focus() on another control on the page to close the SIP.

You can test for the Enter key in the OnKeyUp event for the TextBox and move the focus.

e.g.

```
    private void myAutocompleteBox_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter) {
            addButton.Focus();
        }
    }
```

You can also test for an item selected by the AutoCompleteBox in the Textbox.SelectionChanged event and move the focus.

This post demonstrates doing the latter.

[AutoCompleteBox in Windows Phone 7 « Roger Gullhaug's Blog](http://rgullhaug.wordpress.com/2010/09/08/autocompletebox-in-wp7/)

Comment: I've already tryed to catch the Enter key in the OnKeyDown event, but this event is never fired for the enter key :(
(for other keys, yes)

Comment: I added the code added above in my edit Roger's sample project.. seems to be taking care of business.

Comment: thanks. The KeyUp event is working. What a shame I've only tested the keydown event. Thanks !

Comment: Yea, I didnt really think about it to be honest.. I tested KeyUp because it's a better event in reality than KeyDown for getting the user's intent, but you're right, KeyDown actually doesn't work on this control... odd, but not really of any consequence.